# Passing parameter into T4 runtime template retrieved from a dll in C#

Tags: c#, dll, t4

I have a DLL that has a T4 runtime template and a class that is returning the instance of that template trough a method (the template name is Query.tt and it generated the class Query.cs):

Template from dll:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ template debug="true" #>
<#@ parameter name="TestObj" type="TemplateDLL.Class2" #>

Hellow <#= this.TestObj.s #>!
Hellow <#= this.TestObj.x #>!
```

Class from dll:

```
namespace TemplateDLL
{
   public class Class1
   {
       public Query getQueryTemplate()
       {
           return new Query();
       } 
   }
}
```

I am loading this dll into another project using Reflections:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestDynTemplate2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\somedllpath\TemplateDLL.dll");

           dynamic c =  Activator.CreateInstance(DLL.GetType("TemplateDLL.Class1"));

           var templateInstance = c.getQueryTemplate();

           TemplateDLL.Class2 c2 = new TemplateDLL.Class2();
           c2.x = 3;
           c2.s = "cdfafdafa";


          templateInstance.Session = new Dictionary<string, object>();
          templateInstance.Session.Add("TestObj", c2);
          templateInstance.Initialize();

          var generatedCode = templateInstance.TransformText();

          Console.WriteLine(generatedCode);
        }
    }
}
```

I also have in both projects (int the dll project and in the dll calling project) a definition of a class (TemplateDLL.Class2) that I instantiate (in the calling dll project) and I pass the instance to the dll function that generates the template. The object that I pass is used int the template within the dll.

```
namespace TemplateDLL
{
    class Class2
    {
        public int x;
        public string s;
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine until the object is used in the template when it throws a System.InvalidCastException: [A]TemplateDLL.Class2 cannot be cast to [B]TemplateDLL.Class2. And the it tels me the types A and B origins are not the same.

How can make this work? I am new to c# and T4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# (and in .NET in general) the same *definition* does not mean *the same class*.

`Class2` declared in assembly A and `Class2` declared in assembly B are completely different classes (that coincidentally share same namespace and class name) because a class is defined by both its full name and its assembly (which also includes processor architecture and public key, see [`GetType()` on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details).

You have to share assembly where you declare that type or copy (for example through Reflection) from one type to the other. Something like this:

```
var instanceInBType = instanceInB.GetType();
foreach (var fieldInA in instanceFromA.GetType().GetFields())
{
    var fieldInB = instanceInBType.GetField(field.Name);
    var valueInA = fieldInA.GetValue(instanceFromA);

    fieldInB.SetValue(instanceInB, valueInA);
}
```

Practically you have to accept a *generic* `object` parameter (`instanceFromA`), create a local variable `instanceInB` and copy field by field from A to B. Of course to share type definition is definitely better...